# 404 Not Found! Url Not Found . API key Update How to Solve?

Tags: php, laravel, api, url, routes

My Route API:

```
Route::get('/outline/{key}',"OutlineController@show");
Route::post('/outline',"OutlineController@store");
Route::delete('/outline/{key}',"OutlineController@destroy");
Route::put('/outline/{key}',"OutlineController@update");
```

My Controller Code is:

```
public function update(Request $request ,$key)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'string|required',
        'content' => 'string|required',
        'pseudo' => 'string',
        'email' => 'email|required'
    ]);

    try {
        if($outline = Outline::where('key',$key)->first()){

            $outline = Outline::where('key',$key)->first();

            $outline->title = $request->title;
            $outline->content = $request->content;
            $outline->pseudo = $request->pseudo;
            $outline->email = $request->email;
            $outline->save()->refresh();

            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Success!",
                'outline' => $outline
            ],200);

        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Not found!"
            ],404);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        report($e);
        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Something went really wrong!"
        ],500);
    }

}
```

This Page to show 404 Not Found:

[image]

I have try last 3 hours but no response. Please Solve this...

I try put and patch method but 404 not found page Show..

Advanced Thank You For Help.....

Comment: try to run `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Not Working..@SaurabhMistry

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` to see all your routes are there ?

Comment: Can you paste your full route file here

Comment: Can you show us full route and controller file?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/api/outline/Hz5UK59HRS @AnkurTiwari

Comment: @SmitPipaliya I'm talking about your route.php

Comment: show Question paste controller and route.. @Jitendra

Comment: Have you tried with this URL http://localhost:8000/outline/Hz5UK59HRS

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the "Headers" tab in your Insomnia request?

Comment: Can you upload full controller file and api.php file? @SmitPipaliya

Comment: Route::get('/outline/{key}',"OutlineController@show");
Route::post('/outline',"OutlineController@store");
Route::delete('/outline/{key}',"OutlineController@destroy");
Route::put('/outline/{key}',"OutlineController@update"); @Ankur Tiwari

Comment: Is these routes are in api.php file or web.php file? @SmitPipaliya

Comment: api.php @Jitendra

Comment: Host: localhost:8000
Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2019 11:12:56 +0000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.5
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
date: Tue, 26 Feb 2019 11:12:56 GMT
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 @GeorgeHanson

Comment: @SmitPipaliya I mean't in the request, not the response. You see the tabs where it says "Form", "Auth", "Query" etc? Click on the one that says "Headers" and share a screenshot

Comment: Check weather it is working
`Route::put('/outline/{key}', function () {
    return 'Working';
});`

Comment: Content type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded @GeorgeHanson

Comment: not work..@Jitendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the headers tab of your request, ensure that the following headers have been set. That will tell Laravel that you are sending an Ajax request and not a standard HTTP request.

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, first part of the resolve issues like this check if you can hit the route. So if you are not writing test just use dd() on update;

```php
public function update(Request $request ,$key)
{
    dd($request, $key);

}
```

If you can't hit the route try to use simple rest client like postman or insomnia to create request or simple form like this;

```php
// if you using routes/api.php /api/outline/1234
<form action="/outline/1234" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')

    ...
</form>
```

If you hit the route then your problem lies here;

```php
return response()->json([
                'message' => "Not found!"
            ],404);
```

Comment: This is only API Not form

Comment: Doesn't matter api or not you can check your problem with this way. By the way your querying 2 times with this ```$outline = Outline::where('key',$key)->first()``` just use outside of if statement once.